# I got the following error while automating gmail page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
package webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Gmail {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("arung@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Next")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("welcome");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();


}
```

}

---

I got the following error. Please help me

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Next"}
Command duration or timeout: 186 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit:  http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
```

Comment: could you add the source of the element you are trying to find?

Answer (score 1):

It means that Selenium was not able to find the locator that you have mentioned. Since the issue is on locator with id `"Next"`, it is throwing exception at this point.

I just checked and the locator for this on Gmail page should be with id `"next"` because this is what the HTML shows

```
<input id="next" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Next" name="signIn"/>
```

Use "next" in the code for the id field and it should work.

Also I would recommend -try doing a little bit more of research before posting a question. This is one of the most basic issues faced with Selenium and you will have go your answer if you would've researched a bit- on the web or on this site as well